# update Eclipse Android project to next version

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an android project in Eclipse I started developing in android version 2.2.? (i think).  I want to update the project to run on my 2.3.3 device.  Is there a way to upgrade the project or do I need to create a new one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So based on your question... I just want to say that an Android 2.2 application will run on your 2.3.3 device without changes.  (i.e., applications are forward compatible)

If you still want to change your platform version, read on.

Right click your project in the Project Explorer pane and select "Properties."  The window that comes up will look like the following and you can select a different platform target.

[image: Eclipse Android Project Properties screen shot]

If your project then reports some property related errors in the Problems pane, you can fix those by right-clicking your project again and selecting the `Android Tools` --> `Fix Project Properties` menu item:

[image: Eclipse Android menu Fix Project Properteies]

There's a [`uses-sdk` element](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file, the `minSdkVersion` attribute should always be set to something, especially if you're going to put your application in the Android Market.  The corresponding [API levels for Android are well documented](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html).

Answer (score 0):

I did this myself recently in the Eclipse IDE.

If you right click the project and view properties.  There is a tag where you can select the target framework (2.2.?, 2.3.3, etc.)  Unselect 2.2 and select 2.3.3.

At this point, if you were to save and reopen the project, it would tell you that some properties are messed up.  If you right click the project again, and one of the last few menu buttons will have text along the lines of "Fix Project Properties".  Click that option and afterwards everything should work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I can't add comments yet (apparently), but wanted to add to the above answer.
Yes, as noted above, you can edit project properties to bind to a new target android framework version.  Under Properties, the heading on the left you want to pick is "Android".  And you don't "unselect and select", you simply check the target framework you want (you can only have one active, they are really radio buttons, not checkboxes!).