# Upgrade Eclipse Project from 2.2 to 2.3

Tags: android, properties, upgrade, android-2.2-froyo, android-2.3-gingerbread

I downloaded an android project from code.google.com. 
It is build in Android 2.2.Actually i want to add some functions in this project which were not available in 2.2 and that's why i want to upgrade it to 2.3

I change the Project Properties from Android API level 2.2 to 2.3 as mentioned here: 
[update Eclipse Android project to next version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099019/update-eclipse-android-project-to-next-version)

After setting it to 2.3 API Level, i try to add functions of API level 2.3, but it is continuously giving me error that no such function found and asks to create methods within class.

Please help me experts...

Answer (score 0):

You are changing only the build target of the Project. It will only change the target API in which the project is to be built. The project can still work in devices with API 2.2. So it will show an error when methods which are not compatible in lower versions are used.

To change it, take your manifest file and change the `android:minSdkVersion` to 9 (2.3).

Answer (score 0):

go to project.properties in project folder.
And change target=android-8 to target=android-9.
And in Manifest change

> android:minSdkVersion to 9.

Answer (score 0):

Right click your project in the Project Explorer pane and select "Properties." The window that comes up and you can select a different platform target.

If your project reports some property related errors in the Problems pane, you can fix those by right-clicking your project again and selecting the Android Tools --> Fix Project Properties menu item:

There's a uses-sdk element in your AndroidManifest.xml file, the minSdkVersion attribute should always be set to something, especially if you're going to put your application in the Android Market. The corresponding API levels for Android are well documented.